# C code that reads csv files crashes due to the file being too long

Tags: c, csv

I have a program to reads and prints the phrases in a csv file using C programming language. The program to output the phrase after the set number of commas within the csv file (point variable) .  The csv file is a very long dataset. The C code below has a problem where after a certain amount of outputs it gives an error and closes the file before it reaches the end of the file. In addition to that I want to add another character like (point) called (point2) however instead of it starting from the 10th comma I want the new point to start from 8 and then gets incremented by 7 again.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// fetch the phrase based on the point
void fetchPhrase(int point){

// create FILE pointer variable which will access the file
FILE *fp;

// read character from file
char ch;

int flagEndFile = 0;

// store phrase that is readed from file
char phrase[100];

// work as index for phrase
int index = 0;

// track the ","
int counter = 0;

// open the file in read mode
fp = fopen("input.csv", "r");

// check whether file is opened or not
if(fp == NULL){
printf("File not found!");
exit(1);
}

// read the character untill the file is not end
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){


// check whether character is ',' or not
if(ch == ','){

// increment the counter
counter++;
}

// when we get the "," as well as correct point
if(ch == ',' && counter == point){

// read the phrase until the program does not found ","
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != ','){

// if file is ended then break the loop
if(ch == EOF){
break;
}

// otherwise store phrase into the phrase array
phrase[index++] = ch;
}

// break the loop
break;
}
}

// store null into the character array
phrase[index] = '\0';

// check whether the point is found or not in the file
if(ch == EOF && phrase[0] == '\0'){

// point is not found in the file
printf("There is no point in the 'input' file");

}else{

// otherwise print the phrase
printf("\n Price is: %s", phrase);
}

}


void main(){

// create FILE pointer variable which will access the file
FILE *fp;

// store usr input
int point = 10;


// this loop run untill the user does not enter -999.
while(point != -999){

// call the function which display the phrase
fetchPhrase(point);
//Nexct price value is 7 commas after
point = point + 7;
//printf("The price is %d\n", point);
// get the input from the user
//printf("\nAfter what comma do you want the code to print: ");
//scanf("%d", &point);

}

// close the file
fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: `char ch;` should be `int ch;` to properly detect `EOF`. Please properly indent your code so it is readable. If `int point = 10;` and in your `while()` you `point = point + 7;` how will it every equal `-999`??

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I cant implement `char ch` as it stores the variables, the -999 is just a number that the while loop could run forever because it will never reach -999.

Comment: No, I mean change your declaration from `char ch` to `int ch`. See [man 3 getchar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html). What is the correct return ***type*** for `getchar()`? There is a reason for that, and it's `EOF`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin when I make the change it still crashes unfortunately.

Comment: Give me a second, I think I created a file for this question. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue I see in `fetchPhrase()` is when you find the `','` you want, you read the comma as part of `phrase`. The next big issue I see is since you are reading with `fgetc()`, you are not checking for `'\n'`. So for example when you update `point = point + 7` and there are less than that number of fields left in the current record (line), you then read and ignore the `'\n'` and start attempting to read fields from the next line. Since a `'\n'` isn't a `','` you never increment `counter` so your field count will be off when you begin reading from the next line.

Now it is difficult to know how to handle all your requests for "point" if it wraps and begins reading from the next line without a detailed explanation, but returning if you ask for more fields than are in the line sounds reasonable and could be done with something similar to:

```
#define PHRASE 100

int fetchPhrase (int point, FILE *fp)
{
    char phrase[PHRASE] = "";           /* buffer to hold phrase */
    int ch,                             /* current character */
        index = 0,                      /* phrase index */
        counter = 0;                    /* separator counter */
    
    /* read all chars in line */
    while ((ch = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        /* check if wanted field (point) found */
        if (counter == point) {
            /* protect phrase bounds, while not next separator */
            while (index + 1 < PHRASE && ch != ',' && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
                phrase[index++] = ch;   /* store character in phrase */
                ch = fgetc (fp);
            }
            phrase[index] = '\0';       /* nul-terminate */
            break;                      /* break read loop */
        }
        if (ch == ',')                  /* comma found */
            counter++;                  /* increment counter */
    }
    
    if (counter == point && phrase[0] != 0)     /* phrase found */
        printf ("\n Price is: %s\n", phrase);
    else
        fputs ("There is no point in line.\n", stderr);

    return ch;  /* return stream state good (>0) if not EOF */
}
```

(**note:** untested, no sample data provided, but the points (fields) are zero indexed, meaning if you ask for `point == 0` it will return the 1st field in the line, `point == 1` will be the 2nd field (after the 1st `','`), and so on...)

That way you are only reading characters in the field, not the `','`. Also note `phrase` is *nul-terminated* immediately after it is filled.

**Note:** the other changes. Do not hardcode filenames in functions. Do not use *MagicNumbers*. Pass the open `FILE*` stream as a parameter to your function instead of hardcoding `input.csv` in your function. You should not have to recompile your code just to read from a different filename. For your *MagicNumber* `100` in `phrase[100]`, `#define` a constant any time one is needed. That provides a convenient place at the beginning of your code to make adjustments without having to pick through the body of your code.

You must protect your array bounds when filling `phrase` with characters. If your phrase is longer than your array, you need to stop adding characters while preserving room for the *nul-terminating* character. Checking `index + 1 < PHRASE` does that for you.

Any time your function can succeed or fail, you must declare a meaningful return type for the function to indicate success/failure. In this case, since you want to read from the file multiple times, you need a way to indicate whether `EOF` was reached. Returning an `int` for `true` / `false` is a simple way to indicate success or failure and can be used to indicate whether `EOF` has been reached by returning the result of `ch != EOF`.

**The correct use of `main()`**

Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) In a freestanding environment, the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. See: [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1)

**Passing the Filename to Read as an Argument**

With `int main (int argc, char **argv)`, you can pass information into your program from the command line. `argc` is your *argument-count* telling you the number of command line arguments provided (note: there is always `1` argument, `argv[0]` always holds the program name). So the first argument passed to the program is `argv[1]` and so on. `argv` is an array of pointers to the arguments which are nul-terminated strings with the next pointer after the last string set to `NULL` as a sentinel.

You can check for the filename passed as an argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default) using the following:

```
/* pass filename as 1st argument to program, or read stdin by default */
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int point = 10;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

Now you can pass the open `FILE*` pointer to your function as an argument -- your function can rely on the fact the file has been opened and validated open for reading in the caller:

```
    fetchPhrase (point, fp);
```

You can use also use the return to determine if `EOF` has been reached:

```
    while (fetchPhrase (point, fp) != EOF) {
        ...
    }
```

**Using a Line-Oriented Approach**

While your use of `fgetc()` is fine, it complicates reading records (lines) in your input file. If you instead read each line with a line-oriented input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`, then processing requests for offsets from fields in the file would be limited to the fields contained in the line and would eliminate your testing of `'\n'` to constrain your field requests to a single record.

Those were the thoughts I had on your code. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.